# Scala: Extracting annotation from singleton object via reflection

Tags: scala, reflection, annotations

How can one access the annotation of a singleton object given a string?

I am using Scala version 2.11.6 and plan to upgrade to 2.12 after sorting this issue out.

### Example

Given an (java) annotation

```
public @interface Marked {
  String name();
}
```

and a simplified factory interface

```
trait Instance { def doSomething(): Unit }
trait Factory { def create(): Instance }
```

I would like to check whether a dynamically loaded singleton object is annotated and with what value. The singleton object will be put in the classpath and may be defined as such:

```
class A extends Instance { override def doSomething() { println("A is done.") } }

@Marked(name = "My A Factory")
object AFactory extends Factory {
  override def create(): Instance = new A()
}
```

### What I tried

I can only access the module (singleton object) dynamically and in this way fail to access the annotation. Mostly due to lack of comprehensive documentation I have tried the following expressions which all somehow return an empty list.

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.{universe => ru}
val name = "AFactory$" // This is automatically provided.
val rm = ru.runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)

val classSym = rm.staticClass(name)
println(classSym.annotations)
println(classSym.companion.annotations)
println(classSym.baseClasses(0).annotations)
println(classSym.baseClasses(0).companion.annotations)

val moduleSym = rm.staticModule(name)
println(moduleSym.companion.annotations)
println(moduleSym.asModule.annotations)
println(moduleSym.asModule.moduleClass.annotations)
println(moduleSym.asModule.moduleClass.companion.annotations)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the JVM retain the annotation during runtime, otherwise it wont work =>

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Marked {
}
```

With this change, your code worked.
Edit:
The reason is, that the default retention is "Class", which will make the compiler retain the annotaion in the classfile, but it wont be accessible during the runtime.

Comment: Note that Scala annotations will never be visible at runtime AFAIK